# How to style a Drawer using Material-UI v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In Material-UI `v4`, the `Drawer` component could be styled this way:

```
<Drawer
  variant="persistent"
  classes={{paper: myClassNameHere}}
>
```

where `myClassNameHere` is produced by `useStyles`, which in turn is produced by `makeStyles`.

Migrating to `v5`'s styling solution is proving tricky for this component in particular, because the styling needs to be applied to the inner `Paper` child component instead of to the main `Drawer` component itself.

Is it even possible to style `Drawer` at this point using the new solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass your styled paper to the Drawer like so

```
import styled from "styled-components";
const MyPaper = styled.div`
  //Put your styles here.
`;

const MyDrawer = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer
       PaperProps={{ component : MyPaper }}
    >
      // drawer content
    </Drawer>
  )
}
```

Or you could actually pass an styled div to drawer (since paper itself displays flex, remember to pass `flex:1` to fill out the space)

```
const MyPaper = styled.div`
  flex:1;
`;

 const MyDrawer = () => {
   return (
      <Drawer>
        <MyPaper>
          My Content
        </MyPaper>
      </Drawer>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked: `PaperProps={{component: DrawerPaper}}`, although TS complains:

```TS2322: Type '{ component: StyledComponent ... is not assignable to type 'Partial<PaperProps<"div", {}>>'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'component' does not exist in type 'Partial<PaperProps<"div", {}>>'.```

Comment: What if you add  `PaperProps={{component:<div>H</div>}}`?

Comment: It's because type of styled components is not type of HTML elements which won't cause error since styled components returns HTML element at the end.  You could use `//@ts-ignore` in the line above the error to ignore it

Comment: It complains with `PaperProps={{component:<div>H</div>}}` as well. I guess the transition to `v5` is still ongoing. I'll use `//@ts-ignore` until this is fixed in the library.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do custom and inline style to MUI Drawer and one of which to do so is: to add `PaperProps` and put `sx`

```
<Drawer
   PaperProps={{
      sx: {
         backgroundColor: "#05192D", 
         color: "blue",
         fontSize: 50, 
      }
   }}
 >
   ...
</Drawer>
```

Hope this help, let's me know if your problem still persist!